# Can't get up and running with socket.io

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm running on Windows and using WAMP for a localhost server. I've searched alot for tutorials, tried many things etc. but still nothing works..

### **Current Setup**

So write now, in my www/ directory, I created a folder called `socketiodemo`.

In it, I did `npm install socket.io` as well as installing a few other node packages:

- socket.io
- express
- nib
- stylus

I installed all the above packages even though I don't actually need them. I just installed them since a lot of tutorials needed them but I'd rather not use them and just get to pure socket.io with javascript.

So, here's a snapshot of my directory under www:

- app.js
- index.html
- node_modules

  - socket.io
  - express
  - nib
  - stylus

One of the most stripped down tutorials I found gave me this app.js code, which is the server side:

```
// Require HTTP module (to start server) and Socket.IO
var http = require('http'), io = require('socket.io');

// Start the server at port 8080
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 

    // Send HTML headers and message
    res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
    res.end('<h1>Hello Socket Lover!</h1>');
});
server.listen(8080);

// Create a Socket.IO instance, passing it our server
var socket = io.listen(server);

// Add a connect listener
socket.sockets.on('connection', function(client){ 

    // Create periodical which ends a message to the client every 5 seconds
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        client.send('This is a message from the server!  ' + new Date().getTime());
    },5000);

    // Success!  Now listen to messages to be received
    client.on('message',function(event){ 
        console.log('Received message from client!',event);
    });
    client.on('disconnect',function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log('Server has disconnected');
    });

});
```

And the following index.html for the client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * { margin:0; padding:0; font-size:11px; font-family:arial; color:#444; }
        body { padding:20px; }
        #message-list { list-style-type:none; width:300px; height:300px; overflow:auto; border:1px solid #999; padding:20px; }
        #message-list li { border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; padding-bottom:2px; margin-bottom:5px; }
        code { font-family:courier; background:#eee; padding:2px 4px; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>

        // Create SocketIO instance
        var socket = new io.Socket('localhost',{
            port: 8080
        });
        socket.connect(); 

        // Add a connect listener
        socket.on('connect',function() {
            log('<span style="color:green;">Client has connected to the server!</span>');
        });
        // Add a connect listener
        socket.on('message',function(data) {
            log('Received a message from the server:  ' + data);
        });
        // Add a disconnect listener
        socket.on('disconnect',function() {
            log('<span style="color:red;">The client has disconnected!</span>');
        });

        // Sends a message to the server via sockets
        function sendMessageToServer(message) {
            socket.send(message);
            log('<span style="color:#888">Sending "' + message + '" to the server!</span>');
        }

        // Outputs to console and list
        function log(message) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = message;
            document.getElementById('message-list').appendChild(li);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Messages will appear below (and in the console).</p><br />
    <ul id="message-list"></ul>
    <ul style="margin:20px 0 0 20px;">
        <li>Type <code>socket.disconnect()</code> to disconnect</li>
        <li>Type <code>socket.connect()</code> to reconnect</li>
        <li>Type <code>sendMessageToServer('Your Message')</code> to send a message to the server</li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

The client code is designed to work by dynamically calling `sendMessageToServer('Your Message')` in chrome's inspector.

---

### **Current output**

So, time to run the server. WAMP is online, and going to www/socketiodemo and doing

`node app.js`

Gives me the output:

`info  - socket.io started`

Now, going to localhost/socketiodemo, the following logs are shown repeatedly:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/socket.io/xhr-polling//1338578840544. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/socket.io/xhr-polling//1338578850545. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

And now the server (node app.js) starts displaying the following messages:

```
  info  - socket.io started
  warn  - unknown transport: "undefined"
  info  - unhandled socket.io url
  warn  - unknown transport: "undefined"
  info  - unhandled socket.io url
  warn  - unknown transport: "undefined"
```

Also, in the client, doing `sendMessageToServer('Hello');` simply appends to the ul:
`Sending "hello" to the server!` but doesn't actually do anything to the server. The server just conterminously dumps the `info`s and `warn`s above. The client is also conterminously doing the `XMLHttpRequest` errors shown above.

Could you identify where the problem is? I've actually tried so many tutorials and stuff and this is the closest I've got to getting something working.

If anyone also wants to suggest a tutorial that they know would work, please do so.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770490/socket-io-basic-example-not-working to fix origin issue

Answer (score 4):

Some of the Socket.IO stuff has changed over time. Furthermore, you probably want to serve your HTML and your Socket.IO JS from the same host/port. Give this a try:

**Move your index.html into a `public` directory**

So that you have the following tree:

```
app.js
public/
  index.html
node_modules/
  socket.io
  express
  (whatever else)
```

**Modify app.js to serve the HTML**

Change your app.js to the following JavaScript (only the first few lines change):

```
// Require Express module (to start server) and Socket.IO
var io = require('socket.io'), express = require('express');

var server = express.createServer();

server.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

server.listen(8080);

// Create a Socket.IO instance, passing it our server
var socket = io.listen(server);

// Add a connect listener
socket.sockets.on('connection', function(client){

    // Create periodical which ends a message to the client every 5 seconds
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        client.send('This is a message from the server!  ' + new Date().getTime());
    },5000);

    // Success!  Now listen to messages to be received
    client.on('message',function(event){
        console.log('Received message from client!',event);
    });
    client.on('disconnect',function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log('Server has disconnected');
    });

});
```

With this code, your server will use Express to serve `index.html` when you visit localhost:8080

**Change your Socket.IO code**

In `index.html`, change your `<script>` tag to read: `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` and then change the JavaScript to read (only the first part changes):

```
// Create SocketIO instance
var socket = io.connect();

// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connect',function() {
    log('<span style="color:green;">Client has connected to the server!</span>');
});
// Add a connect listener
socket.on('message',function(data) {
    log('Received a message from the server:  ' + data);
});
// Add a disconnect listener
socket.on('disconnect',function() {
    log('<span style="color:red;">The client has disconnected!</span>');
});

// Sends a message to the server via sockets
function sendMessageToServer(message) {
    socket.send(message);
    log('<span style="color:#888">Sending "' + message + '" to the server!</span>');
}

// Outputs to console and list
function log(message) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = message;
    document.getElementById('message-list').appendChild(li);
}
```

**Start your server and visit localhost:8080**

Note that this skips the WAMP stack all together; Node.js is serving both Socket.IO code *and also your static files*. When you visit localhost:8080, you should see the messages. Note also that you should use `socket.socket.disconnect()` to disconnect and `socket.socket.connect()` to reconnect.

**Source Code**

The source code for a working version of this app is at https://github.com/BinaryMuse/so-10856370; remember to `npm install express socket.io`!

Comment: Awesome, it worked. It's an interesting idea that node.js is now serving actual pages. My next step in my current project is to play around with it a bit until I'm comfortable with both node.js and websockets, then I need some sort of way to communicate with the database with node.js. I guess I'll have to do some of my own research but if you want to guide me to some websites/books you think might be helpful, then I would be grateful!! Thanks again for your help.